# How to achieve dynamic jumping of characters in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating a Unity based game and need to implement the dynamic jumping function of characters.

I have tried some methods, such as adding force or using a physics engine, but it seems that none of these methods have achieved the desired effect. Is there any other better way to achieve this function? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic jumping and why the physics engine did not achieved that you wanted?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.